# Creating Windows Image from VM using Packer

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, packer

I have to create an Image from an existing VM using Packer.[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/build-image-with-packer) is the link I'm following to do so.

Now I have few doubts in this before proceeding further.

1. Can I run all these commands remotely.
2. If yes, where should I install `Packer` , is it on client Machine or remote machine?
3. If it has to be installed on remote machine, from which the image is being created, is there any workaround for that. I will not have access to install anything on the remote machine.
4. No where the VM details are not mentioned. Does that mean, it will automatically take the VM details when we run the commands on the VM?
5. Where can I see the output of the whole process? Will it be available in azure portal?

Any inputs on the above questions are appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: If the answer is helpful or for more help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is something you have misunderstood about Packer.

> The Azure builder can create either a VHD, or a managed image. If you
>   are creating a VHD, you must start with a VHD. Likewise, if you want
>   to create a managed image you must start with a managed image.

It means you must create the image from the image or VHD, not VM.

The answer to your question.

1. Yes, you can run the command remotely, just like Azure CLI.
2. You can install Packer on your on-premise machine.
3. From the description of Packer, it just needs the image information.
4. You can see the output where you run the Packer command.

**Update**

When you want to create the image from VHD file, you can make an instead:

```
"image_publisher": "Canonical",
"image_offer": "UbuntuServer",
"image_sku": "16.04.0-LTS",
```

Into

```
"image_url": "https://my-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/your/custom/image.vhd",
```

If your vm is managed by Azure, you can pay attention to the option of [custom_managed_image](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/azure.html#custom_managed_image_name) and [images in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/managed-disks-overview#images). Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I'm new to Packer and Azure, so kindly bear with me. My requirement is that, I have a VM with some updated applications on it. I have to create a Image from the VM, for which I'm was instructed to use Packer. And also I cannot run any commands directly on VM. It has to be done remotely from another machine. So in the link, I have mentioned in the question, there is no where mentioned the source machine name. Where do I mention it.And also if I run this remotely, how does the script know for which VM I'm creating the image?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have updated my answer, You can take a look.

Comment: So , is the vhd file is of the VM for which I want to create image?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, it means the URI of your VHD file which you want to create the image.

Comment: All I have now is the resource group Name and VM machine name. How would I get this VHD file URI from these details?

Comment: @CrazyCoder You can see the details in the Azure portal. Or you can get the information about the VM with the CLI command `az vm show --resource-group groupName --name vmName`.